# Saving the data for each hour into separate txt files?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import dateutil.parser
import os
import sys
import glob
def connection():
    os.chdir("record_output/")
    mydict = {}
    data_dict = {}
    for files in sorted(glob.glob("*.csv")):
        fo = open(files, "r")
        data = fo.readlines()
        removeHeader = data.pop(0)
        for lines in data:
            lines = lines.strip("\n")
            lines = lines.strip("\r")
            lines = lines.split(',')
            print lines
            dt = dateutil.parser.parse(lines[0])
            hour = dt.hour
```

When I print lines, it gives me the following output:

```
['2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001']
['2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001']
['2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001']
['2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001']
['2014-07-18 02:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10002']
['2014-07-18 02:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10002']
```

I want the outout something like:

File`01:00:00.txt`

```
'2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001'
'2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001'
'2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001'
'2014-07-18 01:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10001'
```

File`02:00:00.txt`

```
'2014-07-18 02:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10002'
'2014-07-18 02:00:00', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '10002'
```

I want the distinguished output for each hour saved in separate text files who's naming convention is based upon the 'Hour' name. Assuming there can be 24 hours.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Just keep track of the current hour. Just open a new file whenever the hour changes.

```
cur_hour = None
for line in lines:
    dt = dateutil.parser.parse(line[0])
    hour = dt.hour
    if hour != cur_hour:
        outFile = open("%d.00.00.txt" % hour, "w")
        cur_hour = hour
    print >> outFile, ', '.join(line)
```